# Change pantheon terminal cursor type?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

How can I change the default cursor to I-beam mode in pantheon terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via `dconf-editor` or via `gsettings` + terminal.

- Open terminal and type in following:

  ```
  # gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings cursor-shape 'I-Beam'
  ```

  To rollback run following:

  ```
  # gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings cursor-shape 'Block'
  ```
- Open `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org.pantheon.terminal.settings`, open `cursor-shape` and set it to I-Beam.

Comment: In **Juno** it is under `io->elementary->terminal->settings->cursor-shape`. And if you want the "_" use the Keyword "Underline".

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal on **Elementary OS** and execute the following command:

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings cursor-shape 'I-Beam'`